# R CMD-Check returns zero errors, but Actions returns five errors

Tags: r, package, cran

I just uploaded my first R package to CRAN for review a few minutes ago. It passed all the tests I gave it (R-CMD-Check, documentation, etc.). However, upon submitting to CRAN, five errors were returned:

[image]

The workflow page does not contain the word "error", nor can I find anything on the page that would be causing these errors.

[link to CRAN submission page that shows workflow errors for the Ensembles package](https://github.com/InfiniteCuriosity/Ensembles/actions/runs/8412629679/workflow)

What are the errors, and how can they be fixed? I've checked the documentation, and don't see anything that matches this set of errors. The package loads and runs flawlessly on two machines on which I've tested it, I don't see any errors running the package.

EDIT: The five errors all have the same mistake, but I'm not sure how to fix it (or even what this is, nor can I find anything about this on the GitHub Actions page for the package:https://github.com/InfiniteCuriosity/Ensembles/actions/):

The error on all five jobs is: r-lib/actions/check-r-package@v2

[image: r-lib/actions/check-r-package@v2 errorl]

Comment: [This page](https://github.com/InfiniteCuriosity/Ensembles/actions/runs/8412629679) gives more details on some of the failures.  You appear to have issues with some of yopur examples and with compilation of some of your documentation.  I can't dig deeper into your logs.  I don't know if that's because I don't have sufficient privilege for your package (most likely) or whether your actions are not set up to provide the necessary detail.  Did you run `devtools::check_xxxx_release` functions as well as `devtools::check` prior to submission?

Comment: Why do you have so many packages in `Depends`? That's bad practice. Most (probably all) of these should be in `Imports`. Anyway, the issue seems to be that an example uses a function from the feasts package, which relies on a function from the fracdiff package. The feasts package only has fracdiff in `Suggests`, which means your example should check if fracdiff is installed and possibly load the package. You could consider adding fracdiff to your `Suggests` or even import it.

Comment: Thank you for the note
```devtools::check``` returns no errors or warnings on two different computers. It was run many times as this was developed, right from the very beginning, hoping to avoid any issues when it got to this point.

The errors first showed up when I actually submitted the package to CRAN. The ```dev tools::check_xxx_release``` returns the error report, which I'm going to check later today.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll move the packages to ```Imports```. Thank you also for pointing out the error in the examples. I did not see the issue with the examples, thank you for finding that. I'll check that later today, and see if ```Suggests``` or ```Imports``` for the fracdiff package solves the issue.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Rhub](https://builder.r-hub.io/)?